# How to embed semi-transparent images in Squib text properly

Tags: ruby, squib

I'm trying to use semi-transparent inline (embedded) png images with the Squib text method. The semi-transparent portions of the images end up rendering much darker than when the image is placed by itself with the 'png' method.

I've tried different blend modes, but none of them yield the desired results.

```
require 'squib'

Squib::Deck.new cards: 1 do
  background color: 'white'

  # This image renders as expected
  png file: 'semi-transparent.png', x: 100, y: 100

  # The semi-transparent portions of this image render much darker than expected
  text(str: ':circle:', x: 200, y: 100) do |embed|
    embed.png key: ':circle:', file: 'semi-transparent.png'
  end

  save_png
end
```

This is an example of the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNg6Z.jpg

Any tips on how I can get the embedded image to match the standalone one would be great.

---

I've opened a bug for this issue here: https://github.com/andymeneely/squib/issues/278

I'm currently remapping my embed tokens to single-character strings with the following function to work around the issue:

```
def remapTokens(x)
 mapping = {':circle:' => '@', ':square:' => '#', ':triangle:' => '^'}
 mapping.each { |k,v| x.gsub!(k,v) }
 return x
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a bug - can you file it over at our issue tracker? https://github.com/andymeneely/squib/issues

If you could also upload a PNG to that issue that causes this problem that'd be great too.

Semi-transparent images are natively supported, so they get rendered the same way. Squib doesn't handle them any differently. The embed.png and png methods call the same thing, so I'm not sure what's going on here. I'd be happy to investigate.

Full disclosure: I'm the Squib dev.

Comment: Will do. Thanks Andy!